# Defining Global Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, global

I want to define an array with the size of **1 byte** that is available for several .c files, thus I need a global array. I know the way for global variables:

```
   //"globals.h"

   extern uint8_t GlobalVar; //Declaration



   //"globals.c"

   uint8_t GlobalVar = 0; //Definition
```

So, for my array I first used typedef to define a byte:

```
   typedef uint8_t byte; //in "globals.h" right at the beginning
```

Then I proceed with declaration and definition of my array:

```
   //"globals.h"

   extern byte GlobalAr[10];


   //"globals.c"

   byte GlobalAr[0] = 0b00001111;
```

But then I get these errors:

> Error         1   conflicting types for 'GlobalAr'
>
> Message       2   previous declaration of 'GlobalAr' was here
>
> Error         3   invalid initializer

If I try the same thing within a function it works perfectly fine i.e.:

```
    typedef uint8_t byte;

    void function()
    {
      byte GlobalAr[10];
      GlobalAr[0] = 0b00001111;
      GlobalAr[1] = 0b11110000;
    }
```

Q1: Can you guys help me figuring out how to define a global array and to initialize it properly?

Q2: Why does the second way work but the first one doesn't?

Would appreciate any kind of help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `an array with the size of 1 byte`..what is the use?

Comment: `byte GlobalAr[0] = 0b00001111;` maybe you used `0` instead of `10`?

Comment: why would you want to do that, it would be very unmaintainable. Can you explain the use case please?

Comment: I want to controll the 8 outputvalues of the outport of my mirkocontroller, therefore it should look like this binary form because it is easier to handle. There over 60 different patterns which should be selected by a select case function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you missed to *define* the array.

IMO, what you want is

```
byte GlobalAr[10] = {0};
GlobalAr[0] = 0b00001111;
GlobalAr[1] = 0b00001010;
```

and so on.

Otherwise,  as per your code

```
extern byte GlobalAr[10];
```

and

```
byte GlobalAr[0] = 0b00001111;
```

you're trying to *redefine* the `GlobalAr` array with a different size[`10` vs `0`], which is wrong.

Also, if you *really* want an *array* of one element *only*, you have to change the declaration and the definition to

```
byte GlobalAr[1] = {0b00001111};
```

and while accessing , you can use `GlobalAr[0]`.

Comment: hmmm I've tried it now to define all elements like you said with the brackets "{0}" but then I get these errors:


Error 1 redefinition of 'GlobalAr'


Message 2 previous definition of 'GlobalAr' was here



I declared and defined it in "globals.h" so I only have to include the header file to use the array. Is this at least correct?

Comment: @BitHunter now what is `Min_pat`? Can you detail a bit, please?

Comment: Sry hit enter to early, it's the actuall name of my array. I just simplified it here to make it simpler to understand

Comment: @BitHunter 1) declare in header file. 2) define and initialize in main `.c` file. that's it. Do take care of the number of elements in both the cases.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it now in a new solution and there it worked so far. I guess I've made a mistake somewhere in my real solution because there I always get a "redefinition of..." error and this error leads me to my one and only definition of this array... I'll take a closer look, maybe I left something....

Comment: `GlobalAr[0] = x;` is not permitted at file scope

Comment: @SouravGhosh
haha^^ just forgot to accept it because I had to go yesterday, thx! :)

Answer (score 1):

This line is completely wrong:

```
byte GlobalAr[0] = 0b00001111;
```

Compiler thinks you are going to:

- define new array (ok)
- with name: GlobalAr (ok)
- with elements of type byte (ok)
- with zero elements inside (hmmm, not so ok, should be 10)
- **and finaly it FAILS** because you want to initialize entire array as integer value (0b00001111)

If you want to define array and initialize its elements you MUST enclose them inside `{}`

```
byte GlobalAr[10] = {0b00001111, 0b11110000};
```

**It is not possible to change elements of array in file scope** as you attemted to. You need to place such code in a function.

Answer (score 1):

To declare the array in your .h file:

```
extern uint8_t GlobalVar[1];
```

In exactly one `.c` file (which should include that `.h` file, in order to generate a compilation error if you have a mismatch) must have the definition:

```
uint8_t GlobalVar[1] = { 0x0F };
```

`0b00001111` is not valid in C, I assume this is supposed to be `0x0F`.

---

The difference with your "code in function" example is that functions may contain both declarations and statements. In that function you declare an array with no initializer, and then use assignment statements to give values to it.

Outside of a function this is not possible; you can only provide *initializers* as part of the definition, and for an array they take the form of `=` followed by a brace-enclosed list which is inserted just before the `;` at the end of the definition.

Comment: You are right, though if I used it within my program I always got errors like "First initialization was here...". Today I've tried it again and it worked (maybe I was already too tired yesterday^^).

In my version C does take numbers in a binary form like 0b00001111, maybe just because it's avr-gcc that implements C for avr programming...

But thx for your help!

Comment: sounds like perhaps the original version had the header-file version including an initializer